# SQL multiple columns select - take an expiry data and a Null column

Tags: mysql, join, merge, count

I have a table with 3 columns: `id, expire, lastwdIf`

How can I make a query so that, for each unique id, I have in the same row the `expiry` column only for the month of December and, in the same row, find the `lastwdIf` (has only one register as null for each id) column valued as null?

| id | expire | last wdIf | Name | Vendor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10/01 | d23dv36 | Juan | 25,5 |
| 15 | 12/04 | 2232cg | Maria | 36,4 |
| 15 |  | null | Maria | 14,1 |
| 10 | 12/17 | 2232cg | Juan | 10,2 |
| 10 |  | null | Juan | 32,10 |

The result must be:

| id | expire | last wdIf | Name | Vendor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 12/17 | null | Juan | 32,10 |
| 15 | 12/04 | null | Maria | 14,1 |

I've tried to do some SELECT cases join, but none works :(

Comment: What is the type of `expire`? What if an id has no `expire` in December? What if it has no null `lastwdif|?

Comment: "I've tried to so some SELECT ..."  Where???  We don't see a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [self-join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp). Join the table with itself, matching rows on id, but only the rows for which `expire` is null. For each ID you will have the data for both December and null as one row.

```
select t1.id, t1.expire, t2.lastwdif, t2.name, t2.vendor
from test t1
join test t2 
  on t1.id = t2.id and t2.expire is null
where left(t1.expire, 3) = '12/'
order by id;
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/hla600wJ).

Note: this will produce a row for *every* row in December.